# html object element show loading progress

Tags: jquery, html-object

I would like to show loading progress once i set the `data` property of my html object element.

This is how i do it currently:

**HTML**

```
<div class=" container row form-horizontal">
    <div id="printModal" class="modal fade in" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg print-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content print-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Print Out</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="detailAlert" class="alert alert-danger display-hide">
                        <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
                        <span>Some Errors have occured!</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <object id="pdfbox" style="width: 100%; height: 800px; overflow:hidden"
                                type="application/pdf"></object>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn dark btn-outline">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Loading Url**

```
    $('#printModal').modal('show');
    var url = '/PurchaseRequisitions/Print?prId=' + prId;
    $('#printModal').find('object').prop('data', url);
```

I tried using the `onloadstart` and `onloadeddata` events in order to display some basic progress but they dont seem to be firing;

```
    $('#pdfbox').on('loadstart', function () {
        alert('common');
        //blockComponent('#printModal.modal-content');
    });
    $('#pdfbox').on('loadeddata', function () {
       // unblockComponent('#printModal.modal-content');
    });
```

The above two events were described in w3school, so not sure what i am doing wrong, but there is no console errors.

Comment: What *is* `#pdfbox` ? `loadeddata` is for media content (video/audio)

Comment: i edited my question. Thank you for loaded data, didnot know that